# How to set the delay based on the number of attacks performed in 1 second?

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints

I would like the delay that defines the interval in which the warrior deals damage to an enemy, was calculated based on a number of attacks per second and not a delay.

**Explaining best, I'd like to define how many times the loop executes per second, not the time interval:**

[image]

**Something like no LOL:**

[image]

Comment: Is your question, "Given a number of attacks per second, how do I calculate the delay between each attack"? - if so, I don't feel there is any need for the answer to be specific to unreal (this has a simple/general mathematical solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edition made based on a very relevant comment from Bilkokuya.**

Before doing any research, I tried to deduce the formula, and I did. It's quite simple.

The formula I had made, was (for the interval of 1 second) divide the number (x) by itself squared (x²):

- x / x² <= example => 2 / 2² == 2 / 4 == **0,5 delay interval**

**In the blueprint of unreal (that I'm doing the game) it looked like this:**

[image]

**With the comment from Bilkokuya I understood that it is only to reverse the number:**

- 1 / x <= example => 1 / 2 == **0,5 delay interval**

**And this calculation for attack speed works for any time interval:**

- 2 / x <= example => 2 / 2 == **1 delay interval**

Comment: Now that you said, I realized. I was so excited that I wanted to share. With the inverse of the number it is possible to do for any interval of time. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing my answer based on your comment, because I considered that you are not intended to make a answer. If you decide to make your own answer, I will revert to my edition.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer, I've reversed the vote as well.